# Objective-C categories with the same name

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-category

I have a set of data classes that I'd like to extend with my own methods by creating categories unique to each class.

When declaring a category, does each category need to have a unique name, or can I reused the same name.

Example. Say I have a List class and ListItem class and I want categories on both. What I'm doing now is declaring as follows:

In List+Additions.h

```
@interface List (Additions) ...
```

In ListItem+Addtions.h

```
@interface ListItem (Additions) ...
```

Is that ok? I can't tell if its consistently working. What is considered the category name? Is it "Additions", or the combination, "ListItem+Additions".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The category names are `List (Additions)` and `ListItem (Additions)`.  So, the two categories are separate and independent.

Something like "ListItem+Additions" is a common convention for the file names which define the categories, but neither the compiler nor the runtime pay any attention to that.

Comment: Asterisk: the compiler **does** notice the file name, how else would the `__FILE__` macro work?

Comment: It *knows* the file name, but it doesn't pay any attention to it. It doesn't base any decisions on it. (Also, the `__FILE__` macro is substituted by the preprocessor, not the compiler.)

Answer (score 2):

> Is that ok? I can't tell if its consistently working. What is considered the category name? Is it "Additions", or the combination, "ListItem+Additions".

Yes, it is ok.

Both the categories have same name: `Additions`, but one is a `List`'s category, and other is a `ListItem`'s category. So there is no clashing of names. This is true even if you would have put both the categories declarations in same file.